# Open screen for a impala query

Tags: linux, impala

I have an impala query in a file and I want to open a screen for this query.

The query is like

```
select * 
from db.test
where date >20201101
```

I will run the file with `impala-shell -f test.sql`
Also is it possible to generate a file with the execution time of the screen after?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible using some more shell scripting.

```
impala-shell -k --ssl -i xx:100 -q "select * from table;" >logfile.txt 2>&1
grep "Fetched" logfile.txt | cut -d " " -f 5 > Run_info.txt  #for Select,Create
grep "Modified" logfile.txt | cut -d " " -f 5 >>Run_info.txt  #for Insert
```

Output will be `0.11s`
You can use this to run all your scripts in loop. If you want you can see how many records fetched/modified too from logfile. You just have to tweak the grep command.